# What type of seabed attracts speckled trout?

Tags: fishing, united-states-gulf-coast

What type of seabed should I be fishing on when trying to catch [speckled trout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cynoscion_nebulosus) along the Texas Gulf Coast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the location and temperature of the water. **Generally, speckled trout can be found in shallow bays and estuaries near grass flats and oyster beds.**

[Texas Parks and Wildlife Department suggests:](http://tpwd.texas.gov/huntwild/wild/species/strout/)

> shallower bays and estuaries with oyster beds and seagrass beds that attract prey species

However, [other sources](http://www.oldschoolfishingsecrets.com/saltwater/speckledtroutfishing.htm) have more specific suggestions depending on the style of fishing:

> Drift your boat over sandy flats, oyster beds, rocky bottoms, and wrecks.

Speckled trout are attracted to bait fish which typically steer clear of wide open sandy bottems.